# How to convert .PDF and .doc/.docx files to .HTML files?

Tags: php, linux, file-conversion

Does anyone know of any software (preferably open source, Linux or PHP) that can convert both PDF and/or DOC/DOCX (and maybe other document formats too: rtf, txt, etc.)  to HTML?

I've got "PDFtoHTML" software working but this not appear to also convert DOC/DOCX files.

Answer (score 1):

You should give [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) a spin. It should be able to convert anything that Open Office can read to anything it can write.

This works on doc/docx and a whole lot of other files. It does not seem to work on PDF's so I guess you're stuck with using 2 separate programs for the job.

Comment: hi jpjacobs, thanks for the tip, i hadn't heard of unoconv, will give it a shot, thanks! -tim

Answer (score 1):

I successfully put a portable version of libreoffice on my host's webserver, which I call with PHP to do a commandline conversion to .docx, etc. to pdf. on the fly. I do not have admin rights on my host's webserver. Here is my blog post of what I did:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126151100/http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2011/11/19/converting-.docx-to-pdf-or-.doc-to-pdf-or-.doc.aspx)

Yay! Convert directly from .docx or .odt to .pdf using PHP with LibreOffice (OpenOffice's successor)!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com)? It allows you to do quite a few more things with docx files.

There is a [generateXHTML method](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/api-documentation/generate_xhtml_from_word_document).

Comment: it looks like PHPDocX does makes .docx files but i'm looking for software that converts .docx files to HTML. Am i confused?